# All Bathroom lights on same circuit flicker

Tags: electrical, bathroom

bathroom lights flicker and stop when exhuast fan on a dimmer is turned on. Multiple bathrooms/lights on same circuit. Sometimes GFCI (new) trips without fan on and only one bathroom light on. Problem existed before GFCI installed.

Comment: The exhaust fan being on a dimmer is a big problem. Exhaust fan motors are normally 50 or 60 Hz modifying the voltage can cause all kinds of problems.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the dimmer is going bad. You may have too many lights on the one dimmer,  do I understand that you have a fan on it too?